# Unity: persistence between scenes practical advice

Tags: unity-game-engine, persistence

So I did a lot of research, and long story short decided to go with making a game manager with dontdestroyonload for persistence.

There are many tutorials, but I'm new and I have many questions in my head when it comes to actually implementing this. It's easy when you just have one player character, but my game has a party of players, their prefabs only need to be spawned in battle, then when the battle is over, I don't need their models...just their stats.

So if I attach all my party members to the game manager, it will keep their stats but also keep everything else:model, battle scripts, etc. I just need to keep their stats. So how do others do it in practice?

I was thinking of adding code to destroy the scripts and components I don't need, then reattach them when a battle is triggered, but I just feel like it's hacky and I'm missing a better established solution out there. I've looked at professional packages and never saw anyone do that, it's like they store the stats somewhere else and just spawn a prefab in battle.

Answer (score 0):

## Why does this code need to be attached to a game object at all?

There is no reason to extend `MonoBehaviour` for things that "store data" and attach it to a GameObject (which is then never destroyed). This is the result of being new to Unity and every time you create a script, Unity automatically has it extend `MonoBehaviour` and you get into the thinking that EVERYTHING has to be attached to a game object and treated like one. You don't have to do this. [Here's a class](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/draco18s/artificer/items/Industry.cs#L16) that doesn't extend anything (it implements ISerializable, but that's not relevant here).

Instead, you might want to look into [scriptable objects](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/scriptable-objects), or have some other method of storing the player data (e.g. your `GameManager` class could be a singleton with a static `instance` reference). What works best for your project is mostly up to you: you know the most about your goals, you need to evaluate your options and figure out what works for you.

Comment: Ok so I thought about this. When a battle ends, I would write all the stats of the unit + store its components and children settings into vars into a scriptable obj, then when I need them again, I just recreate all the components with their settings. Sounds like a lot of code since my units have 30+ components but if that's how its best done I'll do that.

Comment: One thing though, is writing to a scriptable obj essentially like writing to a file? Will it slow down the loading of every scene?

Comment: No, scriptable objects are NOT files. They're classes.